# How to get the common elements beetwen two list and break when is one element is found in Groovy without each method

Tags: groovy

I have two list and I have to get the common elements beetwen both list, I did some implementation with each methods, but I need to break over those each, and it is not possible. In ths way I have to change my implementation.

My current implementation is:

```
def buildMatchTeamsInCategoriesWithPreferences( def preferences, def teamsInCategories )
{
    def preferencesTeamsCategoriesMatch = []
    teamsInCategories.each { team ->
        preferences.each { preference ->
            if ( this.commonPresenter.getString( team?.uid ) == this.commonPresenter.getString( preference?.metaData?.team?.uid ) )
            {
                preferencesTeamsCategoriesMatch << preference
            }
        }
    }
    if ( preferencesTeamsCategoriesMatch?.isEmpty() )
    {
        return null
    }
    return preferencesTeamsCategoriesMatch[ 0 ]
}
```

I have to break, the cycle when is found the first coincidence and don't return the [0] element in the array.

I tried with find and findAll but I have had some problems with the correct result, because I have to break and stop the iteration, when some element is found.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you have some example input and expected output?

Comment: Also, what is `this.commonPresenter.getString`?

Comment: Actually, you can perfectly break an `each` loop: since it's just a closure, you `return` from it instead. Or is there something I've missed ?

Comment: The next is the example of the input and expected result:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could actually do it with `.find()` method. Consider following script:

```
def teamsInCategories = [
        [uid: '1234-1234-1234', name: 'Lorem ipsum'],
        [uid: '1234-1234-1235', name: 'Dolor Sit'],
        [uid: '1234-1234-1236', name: 'Amet Test'],
        [uid: '1234-1234-1237', name: 'Test Test']
]

def preferences = [
        [id: 6, team: [uid: '1234-1234-1236', name: 'Amet Test']],
        [id: 7, team: [uid: '1234-1234-1237', name: 'Test Test']],
        [id: 8, team: [uid: '1234-1234-1238', name: 'A']],
        [id: 9, team: [uid: '1234-1234-1239', name: 'B']]
]

// get a list of uids only
def uids = teamsInCategories*.uid

// find the first preference that matches uid from first list
def preference = preferences.find { pref -> pref.team.uid in uids }

println preference
```

It does not reflect 1:1 your use case, but it is only an example. What happens in this script is we create `uids` list containing all `uid` values from `teamsInCategories` (e.g. `['1234-1234-1234', '1234-1234-1235', '1234-1234-1236', '1234-1234-1237']`) then we call `preferences.find()` that will return first element from `preferences` list that matches our predicate - `pref.team.uid` exists in `uids` list.

Running this script produces following output:

```
[id:6, team:[uid:1234-1234-1236, name:Amet Test]]
```

I hope this answer gives you an idea how to find first common element in two different lists.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `findResult` method on `Collection` (doc [here](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html)). For the original implementation:

```
def buildMatchTeamsInCategoriesWithPreferences(def preferences, def teamsInCategories) {
    teamsInCategories.findResult { team ->
        def uidA = commonPresenter.getString(team?.uid)

        preferences.findResult { preference ->
            def uidB = commonPresenter.getString(preference?.metaData?.team?.uid)
            (uidA == uidB) ? preference : null
        }
    }
}
```